# How could I know which monitor the window handle belongs to on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, multiple-monitors

I am trying to capture the image of the active window. It works well for one monitor, but what if there are multiple monitors?

The solution I use is:

```cpp
if(auto handle = GetForegroundWindow(); handle != nullptr){
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(handle, &rect);
    
    auto screen_list = QGuiApplication::screens();    
    auto pixmap = screen_list[0]->grabWindow(0, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
}
```

The problem is, how could I know which screen the active foreground belongs to when there are multiple windows?

Any API I could use to find out the relationship of the handle and the screen?

Comment: MonitorFromWindow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow

Comment: @SimonMourier that should be posted as an answer rather than a comment

Comment: That answers the question but doesn't solve the problem. If a window straddles more than one monitor, the code will only capture part of the window. I don't know how this Qt API is intended to be used.

Comment: @IInspectable Is it possible to find out the monitors the window crossing(ex : monitor 1 , monitor 2)? And the coordinates of that window in each screen?

Comment: You'll have to manually piece the information together. You already know `GetWindowRect`. Now you'll need [`MonitorFromPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfrompoint) and [`GetMonitorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow) and [`IntersectRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-intersectrect) and put the pieces together. Or have the system [capture the window](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/) for you.

Comment: How about ignoring the screens and using [`QWidget::render`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#render) instead? The doc example shows how to create a `QPixmap` in 2 lines, which you can use further down your code or save on disk.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - wasn't sure it matched the question (seems it doesn't as of now?), and I don't know qt, so wanted to avoid usual downvotes...